# How do I set a virtual attribute on an existing model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, attributes, attr

So I have a `User` model that has a `first_name` and `last_name` column.

I would like to create a new virtual attribute called `username`, that I can access even in my routes file.

I tried doing this:

```
attr_accessor :username 

  # getter
  def username
    @username
  end

  # setter
  def username=(user)
    @username = "#{user.first_name}.#{user.last_name}"
  end
```

But when I try to set it, I get a wrong number of arguments error.

```
[27] pry(main)> u.username=(u)
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)
from     
[28] pry(main)> u.username = u
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)
from
```

`u` is a valid `User` record.

Ideally, I would like to do two things. I would like to be able to check the `user.username` for all `User` objects in my DB and it should return per the above `setter` method.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think, you have a problem somewhere else. It's not easy to find out what's going wrong with your code without seeing it, but this code itself works without any errors:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def username=(value)
    @username = value
  end

  def username
    @username
  end
end

user = User.new(:first_name => "Bill", :last_name => "Gates")
user.username = "billgates"
user.username
```

Or you can use `attr_accessor` to replace manual definition of getter and setter:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :username
end
```

Take a look on this screencast to clarify things: http://railscasts.com/episodes/16-virtual-attributes

Comment: No need for me to specify the `attr_accessor :username` on my `User` model?

Comment: You can use only `attr_accessor` instead of manually implemented getter and setter.

Comment: If I use just `attr_accessor`, how do I set the `username` attribute? Just normally with an assignment statement?

Comment: Yep, `attr_accessor` is just a method that defines getter and setter for you. Added this fact in my answer above.

Comment: Ahh ok. I thought I had to do both. That may have been the issue. Thanks!